# Switching to local database when data connection unavaliable

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I'm in the process of building a mobile companion app for a database system.

As the mobile app won't always have access to a data connection, I need to save any record changes to the local database on the tablet/phone when the internet is unavailable.

My initial thought was to simply use something like

```
public bool TestConn()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("some connection string")
        bool result; 
        try
        {
            conn.Open(); 
            conn.Close();
            result = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data Connection not found");
            result = false;
        }

        return result;

    }
```

then wrapping using an `if` statement to switch between the 2 databases ie. `if true use remote, else use local`

Is there a better way to handle this? I considered using a try-catch system where if the exception thrown is that it can't connect then it saves to the local database instead (assuming that can even be done). Is this even practical given the potential error codes that can be thrown?

Comment: Do you later push changes from local database to server when connection becomes available?

Comment: I recommend you use the local db as primary source and sync with the remote db as soon as the connection established. You'd better use different threads to sync your db.

Comment: No, currently it is done as a manual sync when the user knows they have a data connection

Comment: @ali so approach it with the assumption that there is no data connection, use a separate thread to check if one is avaliable, then upload the changes if there is?

Comment: @Takarii Yes, definitely. Because this simplifies your tasks and seperates the real business with the synchronization issues.

Comment: @ali I assume something as simple as a timer (with a reasonable limit) in the second thread would be more than enough to satisfy this?

Comment: I agree with @ali. It is not very complicated to write a "I couldn't talk to this DB, so I'll use this one" scenario, it is syncing them up which is the problem. For a start, if you write one piece of data remotely, then go offline, write a second piece locally, then try to use both, you won't have it all. Similarly when you go back online, you will need to know what needs updating or not. If you have dodgy signal you may be flicking on and off a lot. It is simpler and more robust to just write everything to one place and let another process/thread synchronize immediately or when available.

Comment: @Takarii It depends on your needs actually. You can either run a seperate thread which is always on or use a simple Timer. I think you should focus on not to block the UI thread.